# jquery keypress issue

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have this code for redirecting when a key is pressed:

```
$('body').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode==66){ window.location = "page.php"; }
    });
```

Ok but, how can i make it not applicable if the user has an input field in focus on the page?

Comment: `if ($(event.currentTarget).attr('id')==='inputId') return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may be.

```
if ( $("*:focus").is("textarea, input") ) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test `event.target` and see what kind of element it is. If it's an `input`, return without doing anything. Specifically,

```
if (-1 != ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(event.target.nodeName)) return;
```

EDIT: Hm, are you guys sure about `event.currentTarget`? I see several people mentioning `currentTarget` instead of `target`, but wouldn't `event.currentTarget` always be the `body` element, where the listener is bound?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode==66 && !($(event.currentTarget).attr('id') ==='inputElement')){ window.location = "page.php"; }
});
```

OR

```
$('input').bind('keyup', function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode==66 && !($(event.currentTarget).is(":focus"))){ window.location = "page.php"; }
});
```

Comment: I'm not that adept with jqyery, but is 'inputElement' a variable? If so is there any way so it covers all input fields instead?

Comment: Yea, the inputElement is an id of the element you want to exclude. I also modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) selector.

```
$("input").is(":focus")
```

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/CegR7/2/

```
$('body').bind('keyup', function (event) {
    // If 'b' is pressed & no input is focused
    if (event.keyCode == 66 && !$("input").is(":focus")) {
        alert('Redirecting');
    }
});
```